# Need sample Applications to develop my own site and application in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sample

I am developing a small and simple web application for a hotel in asp.net using C#. It is a web site which gives hotels information and we can order items from that site. I want a reference source code to develop this application.

Before a year there were sample application on www.asp.net such as myWebPageStarterKit. But now there are not sample applications. From where i could get such sample applications..??

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using **ASP.NET MVC 2** for new web development.

You can find proper 'real-world' sample application called NerdDinner and 185-page PDF walkthrough 'how-each-line-was-written' on [Code Plex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/). Nerd Dinner has many nice features, like intergration with maps or OpenID.

Running app is here: http://www.nerddinner.com/

You can also check [Open Source Projects and Starter Kits](http://www.asp.net/community/projects) on www.asp.net

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Official website still have a lot of open source Applications (eCommerce,CMS,etc )
You can check them . But in your case you need an example for Hotel management system or some thing like this.. I recommended to visit sourceforge.net and search for Hotel Management System . Also you can check sourcecodester.com, Codeproject.com .....

I hope this will be useful